# Javascript Xpath and default namespaces

Tags: javascript, xpath, xml-namespaces

I have some JavaScript/Xpath which isn't working as I would expect. ([available on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chKZc/)) It would seem that I'm doing something wrong with an XML namespace, preventing me from querying for my elements by their node (tag) names.

If I try querying for all child nodes of the current node, I find the element `myElement` without problem:

```
    var xpathResult = xmlDoc.evaluate( "child::*", rootElement, nsResolver, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
    var queryEl;
    if(queryEl = xpathResult.iterateNext()) {
        alert("child::* found element " + queryEl.nodeName);
    }
    else {
        alert("child::* found nothing!");
    }
```

... but if I specifically target the nodes with `myElement` node (tag) names I get no results:

```
    /* Now try getting only those children with nodeName `myElement` */
   xpathResult = xmlDoc.evaluate( "child::myElement", rootElement, nsResolver, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
    var queryEl;
    if(queryEl = xpathResult.iterateNext()) {
        alert("child::myElement found element " + queryEl.nodeName);
    }
    else {
        alert("child::myElement found nothing!");
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please split you problem to show just the problem? As a short and (in)valid example?

Comment: @powtac - Tried... but the code really only creates an XML doc and then makes 2 queries against it. It really is just a test case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this as your resolver:

```
var nsResolver = (function (element) {
    var
      nsResolver = element.ownerDocument.createNSResolver(element),
      defaultNamespace = element.getAttribute('xmlns');

    return function (prefix) {
       return nsResolver.lookupNamespaceURI(prefix) || defaultNamespace;
    };
} (xmlDoc.documentElement));
```

You will also have to select the elements like this:

```
"child::default:myElement"
// where 'default' can be anything, as long as there is a namespace
```

Further reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createNSResolver
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript (*=> Implementing a Default Namespace Resolver*)
- http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathNSResolver-lookupNamespaceURI

Your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chKZc/5/  (*updated*)

Comment: In the end XPath wasn't the best solution anyways... but this seems to work.